# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. Sqlparameter array

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net, prepared-statement

I need help.. please tell me what wrong i did in this code, i messed up during passing parameter array to command.
my store procedure is correct, connection string is also correct..

```
  internal string addmember(string name, string dob, string city, string state, string mobile, string email, string pass)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>();
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mname",Convert.ToString(name)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mdob",Convert.ToString(dob)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@MemailId",Convert.ToString(email)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mpassword", Convert.ToString(email)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@McontactNo", Convert.ToString(mobile)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mcity", Convert.ToString(city)));
        param.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mstate", Convert.ToString(state)));

        string result = Convert.ToString(executescaler(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "add_members", param.ToArray()));
            return result;
    }

    private string executescaler(string con, CommandType commandTyp, string procedure, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
    {
        string res;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = commandTyp;
            cmd.CommandText = procedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
            res=  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

usually i use sqlhelper so never need to go through deep in ado.. but now im suffering because of that.. **i dont get how to pass sqlparameter array to command**

Comment: You may have other issues but you never assigned your connection to the command.

Comment: Also, you are converting strings to strings, makes no sense. Assigning `email` to 5 of your parameters. Using double `@@` symbols on your parameters.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's pretty accurate.

Comment: yep i did lots of mistakes silly one thank you all of you for helping.. now its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell your `SqlCommand` that it should work with your `SqlConnetion`.
Also, `SqlCommand` implements the `IDisposable` interface so you should be using it inside the `using` statement:

```
private string executescaler(string con, CommandType commandTyp, string procedure, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
{
    string res;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedure, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = commandTyp;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
            connection.Open();
            res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```